# Distinguish red color from white is HSV or similar color space?

Tags: colors, color-space, hsv

Red color has `H=0` in [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). White color has `H=0, S=0, V=1`. I.e. `H(Red)=H(White)`.

So, if comparing colors by Hue, how to calculate "likelihood" coefficient which would take into account that white color is not red (or that white color is all hues).

Comment: You can't just use the hue to get a meaningful result. In this case, the saturation is what matters -- with S=0, the value of H becomes irrelevant. For any given value of `V`, you get a circle. The `H` value gives you an angle around that circle, and the `S` value specifies a distance from the center of the circle. S=0 specifies the center of the circle, regardless of the angle.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so what to do?

Comment: It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to measure similarity between colors, consider using one of the (several) Delta E formulas.

Comment: I want to detect given hue in image. Say, red or green.

Comment: Well, I guess I'd use both the Hue and the saturation (at least check for saturation being non-zero).

Answer (score 0):

In the `HSV` color space the `S` channel represents color saturation. `S==0` means the color is a shade of gray (regardless of `H`, the higher `V` is, the brighter it is). The larger the `S` value is, the less grayish it gets. You would probably also want to look at the `V` value, since if `V==0` you'll have black pixel regardless of `H & S`.
When you want to compare two colors you should use all three channels, you may wait them differently but you probably don't want to omit any of them.

Answer (score 0):

HSV colorspace is a cone, so likelihood of a color being red is a distance in that cone between red and the other color.

[image: HSV cone]

Comment: Hello. if I have the H value of a whitish color, how can I get  that of red ?